# How to convert json values into list in html/javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, flask

I'm retrieving data from my flask app as json and trying to turn my json values into a list.

In my html I have the following:

```
<script>
...
 series: [{
name: 'Installation',
data: [{% for x in results %}{{ x.TestInstallation }}{% endfor %}]},
...
</script>
```

`data:` above should have values displayed as a list:

```
data: [10957, 10372, 10256, 10074, 8816, 8605, 9524, 10888, 11188, 10305, 13367, 10775, 9963, 12758, 13361, 10843]
```

my current input for `data:` is the following:

```
data: [1095710372102561007488168605952410888111881030513367107759963127581336110843]},
```

How can I turn values assigned to `data:` into a list?

Comment: It's a bad practice to generate lines of JavaScript based on the logic of another language. You'd probably want to output the JSON as global variable in JavaScript, or create an endpoint to get the JSON from. Then let JavaScript handle the JSON on the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to loop through the array in the rendering engine, you can pass it  as JSON  with the JSON filter

```py
@app.route('/view')
def view():
    data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    # render the template with our data
    return render_template('view.html', page_title = '12345', data=data)
```

and in the template

```py
<script>
...
 series: [{
name: 'Installation',
data: JSON.parse('{{ data | tojson }}'),
}]
...
</script>
```

More about Filters :
[Standard Filters](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters)